# get promise data through intermediate service angular 5

Tags: angular

I have an issue getting promise data through intermediate service.

There is a component, intermediate service and http service.

My component calls intermediate service and then call goes to http service through intermediate service.

Http service returns promise data, I think I am not able to process it in intermediate service hence nothing is returning to my component.

When I call Http service directly from component, it works well, I see the data coming on the UI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**component code.**
Here is the method which calls method from intermediate service

```
public getDriversAndCars(){
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        this.vehicleService.getVehicle()       
        .then(
          res => {                                    
           console.log("length"+this.listOfVehicles.length)
           this.getDriver();
         resolve();

        },
          msg => { // Error
          reject(msg);
          }
        );
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Code from Intermediate Service

```
public getVehicle(): Promise<Vehicle[]> {

    this.associationservice.getVehicle(25, this.currentPageIndex, this.searchText)
      .then(
        res => {
          this.apimodel = res                         
          console.log("data" + this.listOfVehicles[0].assignedTo)
        },

    )
    return Promise.resolve(this.convertToVehicleModels(this.apimodel));

  }
```

code from Http Service

```
getVehicle(pageNumber: number,pageIndex: number, searchKeyword: string): Promise<VehicleResourceApiModel> {

    if (pageIndex !== 0 && searchKeyword.trim() !== '' && pageNumber !== 0) {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
        return  this.http.get<VehicleResourceApiModel>(api).toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            return response
        })
        .catch(err => err);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your intermediate service might be the problem. You are returning a resolved promise for `this.convertToVehicleModels(this.apimodel)` while `this.apimodel` is still undefined.  Your client gets back the result of this function immediately, while your associationservice is still retrieving and returning your actual data.

I suggest you modify your intermediate service something like this...

```
public getVehicle(): Promise<Vehicle[]> {
    return this.associationservice.getVehicle(25, this.currentPageIndex, this.searchText)
      .then(res => this.convertToVehicleModels(res))
}
```

This way the `convertToVehicleModels` method isn't called until your actual data are retrieved from your service, and your return value from `getVehicle` is the result of that promise chain.